# Dual phone SIM card - how to disable both SIM's

Tags: dual-sim

I've a dual phone SIM card (Pocophone). How can I to disable both SIM's without power down everything?

Comment: Airplane mode..

Answer (score 0):

Simply switching on Airplane/Flight mode will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Usually in dual phones in android settings there is a setting as which sim to use for call,data ,text I had such a setting in my sony xperia.I am not sure about it in other phones because my Mi A3 does not have such a setting. Look in your phone settings sim setting and there should be setting for each sim in tray.
If you have such a setting then only you can disable both sim the way you want to.